# MySQL template with Zabbix Agent cannot fetch data

Tags: mysql, zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

Zabbix server is version 6.2

My pc is running Windows 11 and I install Zabbix agent onto it.
I use the template `MySQL by Zabbix agent` to monitor mySQL

### I did what the setup procedure says:

Requirements for template operation:

1.Install Zabbix agent and MySQL client.

2.Copy template_db_mysql.conf into folder with Zabbix agent configuration (/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/ by default). Don't forget to restart zabbix-agent.

3.Create MySQL user for monitoring. For example:
CREATE USER 'zbx_monitor'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT,PROCESS,SHOW DATABASES,SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'zbx_monitor'@'%';

4.Create .my.cnf in home directory of Zabbix agent for Linux (/var/lib/zabbix by default) or my.cnf in c:\ for Windows. For example:

```
[client]
user='zbx_monitor'
password='<password>'
```

But I still cant get any data.

I can see the error `Cannot fetch data: Error 1045: Access denied for user '3306'@'localhost' (using password: NO).`

Has anybody encounter this kind of issue?

Any help is appreciated.